# How to set/get base_path in D8?

Tags: 8

How do I get the base_path in Drupal 8? When I use the `base_path()` function it always returns just the `/`. I know in Drupal 7 you could set the base_url in the settings.php file, but how do I set it in Drupal 8?

I'm trying to create an absolute url for social media sharing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for [`$base_url`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21globals.api.php/global/base_url/8) global:

```
global $base_url;
```

If you want to have this in a preprocess function, you'd have to call it *within* that function; for example:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_whatever(&$variables) {
  global $base_url;
  // Now you can use it.
  $variables['base_url'] = $base_url;
}
```

Comment: I tried that, and it too only returns `/` - what ended up working was calling `$GLOBALS['base_url'];`

Comment: That's strange; it shouldn't work that way. I tested it on a couple of D8 sites (live and dev) and it works fine. `$GLOBALS['base_url']` is equivalent of the code I wrote above.

Comment: I also thought it should do the same thing. What I did is add `global $base_url` to the top of my themename.theme file and then in one of my preprocess functions I tried accessing $base_url, and I get an error 'Undefined variable: base_url' ? am i doing something wrong there?

Comment: Yes :) you need to add it within your preprocess function. I'll update the answer.